# Statistics Question: Running a regression and only estimating an intercept

Tags: statistics, derivatives, optimization, summation

Let $\beta_{0}$ with a tilde over be the solution to:

$$\min_b\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - b_0)^2$$

Show that $\beta_{0}$ with a tilde over is equal to $\bar y$.

My teacher told me to take the derivative with respect to $b_{0}$ and equal that to zero but I don't know how to take the derivative of that. The $b$ on the $\min$ is really $b_{0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the derivative of $(y_1-b_0)^2+...+(y_2-b_0)^2$, where $y_i$ are just numbers, and the coefficient $b_0$ is a variable.  Set that derivative equal to zero, and divide everything by $2$.

What happens?

Comment: $$\bar y=1/n*sum_{i=1}^n (b_0)$$ thanks for the tip. If you know what should I do next it would be great

Comment: The sum of the $\sum_i y_i=n*b_0$    You forgot all the $b_0$ are the same.